# Wired problem, RecyclerView do not show items on some specific Samsung Galaxy devices

Tags: android, xml, layout

I'm developing a media player app and it's working great on all devices that also run on android 10
but i have a wired problem in some phones like **galaxy A70, mi note 10 lite, galaxy A71**
the app do not show the items and also sometime crash in the beginning
i first thought that it was a problem regarding the reading of the external storage, but it asks for permission and its seems that this is not the problem here.

how can it be that it works on most of the devices but not on the others even if they have the same android version

thank you in advance

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvAnimals);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    adapter = new viewadapter(this, audioList);
    adapter.setClickListener(this);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

this is xml

```
   <RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/rvAnimals"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/download"/>
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
```

Comment: What is the stacktrace for the crash?

Comment: there are no crash just no show on specific divises